# Add 'Authorization' Header in Header Filter for Responses in Apache Camel

Tags: java, http-headers, filtering, apache-camel, response

I'm filtering certain headers in my json response. I'm currently using setOutFilterPattern() from DefaultHeaderFilterStrategy class to filter these. However, whenever I add Authorization in the filter, every time I do a request, it keeps on asking me for login details and doesn't seem to accept my login details.

I just need to remove this: Authorization=[Basic c2FuZGJveEFwcDpwQDU1dzByZA==] from the response header.

I would appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide what you have done so far?

Comment: It could be helpful if you can share us with your camel route.